# Synchronous calls with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, synchronous

Can I make use of jQuery AJAX API and make a synchronous calls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like Obama would say:  YES YOU CAN !

[jQuery .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Setting

```
async = false
```

within the .ajax() handler will do the trick.

Comment: This functionality is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: What's the recommended alternative?

Answer (score 3):

While jQuery can make sync AJAX calls by setting the synch:false property, this causes the browser to hang until the AJAX completes. Using a flow control library like [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) enables you to make synchronous calls without tying up the browser:

```
$.each(ajaxObjects, function(i, ajaxCall){
    Frame(function(next)){ // declare the callback next here

        ajaxCall.complete = function(data){
            // do something with the data
            next(); // go to the next ajax call
        }
        $.ajax(ajaxCall);

    });
}
Frame.init();
```

This series of AJAX calls will be made in order, each waiting for the previous to complete, without making the browser hang. Also has the added benefit that the data returns from the ajax calls in a predictable order, as opposed to asynchronous calls which return in a random order.

Comment: One thing I'm unclear on that's kind of important to me: when does Frame.init() return in your answer? Before, or after all those calls are complete?

Comment: Frame.init simply tells Frame that when it receives a job, it should run the job. In Frame v2, it was renamed to Frame.start. The alternative use would be if you wanted to add a bunch of things to the Frame que, but didn't want Frame to start running the jobs yet. Frame will simply hold all the jobs until .start() is called.