# Return value from function with ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Synchronous calls with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery)

I am trying to return a value from a function that contains an ajax call (please see code below).

The returnValue variable is undefined at the alert and when it returns.  Can anyone help please?

```
function getLightboxImages(){

    var returnValue;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://test.domain.com/WebService.svc/GetAllI",
        data: { id: "2", hash:"MaD01" },
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (result) {
            returnValue = result
        }
    });

    alert(returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: The success function is called asynchronously when the AJAX request is complete.

Answer (score 2):

The alert would have to be placed in the success function, as that is called when ajax returns.  What you have above will send the request and then try to alert the returned value before the request is completed.

Comment: @Xander: Yes, it is asynchronous. It's not possible to make a synchronous JSONP request.

Answer (score 2):

try this code, for JSONP you have to use callback function rather than success method.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://test.domain.com/WebService.svc/GetAllI',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackfunction",
        error: function () {
            alert("Error in Jsonp");
        }
    });

    function jsonpCallbackfunction(responseData) {
        alert(responseData);
    }
```

http://cmsnsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/02/how-to-use-cross-domain-ajax-request.html#0

Answer (score 1):

```
function getLightboxImages(){
    var returnValue;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://test.domain.com/WebService.svc/GetAllI",
        data: { id: "2", hash:"MaD01" },
        async: false,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (result) {
            returnValue = result
        }
    });

    alert(JSON.stringify(returnValue));

    return returnValue;
}
```

Cross-domain requests can only be async, as cross-domain requests rely on a dynamic script tag, which can never be synchronous and must use datatype json and the GET method.

For same domain requests, try stringifying json objects before alerting, like above!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make synchronous JSONP requests.

Use a callback instead of return:

```
function getLightboxImages(callback) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://test.domain.com/WebService.svc/GetAllI",
    data: { id: "2", hash:"MaD01" },
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (result) {
        callback(result);
    }
  });
}
```

Usage:

```
getLightboxImages(function(result){
  alert(result);
});
```

Comment: @Xander: Yes, it is asynchronous. If you make a JSONP request, the `async` setting is ignored, as you *can't* make a synchronous JSONP request.