# let synchronous code wait an asynchronous call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form of which I catch the submit event. I have to wait for a `$.post` call in order to decide whether to submit it. I've tried this:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(event){
  var data = null;

  $.post("/post/call").then(function(_data){
    data = _data;
  });

  if ( $.isPlainObject(data) && data.status === 'ko' ) {
    return false; // Do not submit the original form
  } else {
    // Submit the original form
  }
});
```

But `data` results to be always `null`, also if `_data` is valorized, because `$.post` is an asynchrounous call. How can I wait for the `$.post` call to be completed?

EDIT: As wrote in the comments, I would like to avoid `$.ajax({async: true})`, because it freezes the page; is there any way to get the same effect without freezing the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronous calls with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery)

Comment: Why not just put what you want to wait to do at the end async callback?

Comment: where do you get then .then() from. a callback function gets attached in the post with a comma. your if must also be in the callback, because data is not set before the post is completed.

Comment: Use synchronous call as `Felix Kling` advised. Everything, available with `$.post` is as well available via `$.ajax`;

Comment: I would like to avoid $.ajax({async: true}) , because it freezes the page; is there any way to get the same effect without freezing the page?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question then. I thought you want to make the call synchronous. Of course you should avoid synchronous calls if possible.

Comment: my english is poor, so probably what I wrote was not so clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have some sort of flag that says the form is to be submitted or not as well as that the ajax is processing. Then when the ajax call passes, call `$('#my_form').submit()` to send the form.

Loosely,

```
var validated = false;
$('#my_form').submit(function(event){
   if (validated) {
      return true;
   }


  $.post("/post/call").then(function(_data){
    var data = _data;

    if ( $.isPlainObject(data) && data.status === 'ko' ) {
       // Do not submit the original form
    } else {
      validated = true;
      $('#my_form').submit();
  }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: You probably should add another flag which indicates whether a call is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVC / C#, and can use a Json request to access your web service, know the following.

```
$.getJSON
```

Is asynchronous

```
SOLUTION: $.ajax
```

Can be set to synchronous