# how to block on ajax call (I want it to block)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Ajax uses callbacks, as it's `A`synchronous.

**I want my call to the remote URL block until there's some answer**, exactly as in Ajax, but without the asynchronous part, or shall I say I want to make a JAX call.

Is there any technique to make the following happen (uses JQuery) (... solution with JQuery or anything else):

```
function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/foo"
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        return data;
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        return null;
    });
}

var data = get_data();
// process `data`
```

I'm just wondering - want to learn.

Actually there are times where blocking until a reply would fit fine. I'm not saying I want the browser to block, just the script runtime.

Comment: write `async : false` with ajax option

Comment: jQuery $.ajax has `async` property. If you set it to false it will block.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronous calls with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery) -- you cannot block the runtime without blocking the browser though. And you cannot return the response from the callbacks, you have to assign it to a variable and return that one from the actual function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply set the `async : false` boolean when using jQuery ([check the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). Take note: **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.**

If you don't want to use jQuery or want to know what's going on under the hood, [read this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",false);
xmlhttp.send();
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Do wonder why you don't want it to be async though...

Comment: First, thank you . Second, the note regarding jQuery 1.8 isn't clear. Also, the docs say about `async` the following: `.. as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive`. How do I avoid the browser blocking then? This is obviously unacceptable.

Comment: In another thought, it's another question. Thank you, again.

Comment: @Poni did you find out the answer to this other question you mentioned ? did you create a stackoverflow question for it? care to link to it?

Comment: This is old but felt the need to explain why someone might want to do this. Here's my reason:  I have a parent ajax call that returns any number of ids.  Those ids then need to be fed into a second ajax call.  It doesn't take much to overwhelm the browser's internal request queue (reportedly 6000 on Chrome).  Therefore I am using webworkers to make these calls without blocking the main page script.

Comment: @MarcoK Here's another example of why you'd want to do blocking: you have two independent ajax calls (they shouldn't know about each other) but the first one you call takes a longer to complete. The second depends on database changes from the first. You could add a lock field to your database but then you have to test for it everywhere. It's much easier just block on the slower ajax call and make sure you call it first.