# can a synchronous (blocking) ajax call block the browser's UI?

Tags: javascript, ajax

This question is jQuery oriented, but not necessarily exclusively.

**The short question:**

**Can synchronous ajax call block a normal button from being clicked on?** My testings show it doesn't happen, but maybe another browser makes problems.

**The long question:**

In another question I've asked, [how to block on ajax call (I want it to block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213889/how-to-block-on-ajax-call-i-want-it-to-block), the guys said that the browser will block in some cases.

Actually even the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) of jQuery say:
`Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.`

I'm trying to:
**1. Understand how/why that would happen.**
**2. Assess the probability of that to happen.**

From my understanding, which might be incorrect:
I imagine that "locking" will happen to the page's UI if I, as the dev, didn't build/update the UI before the ajax call itself, which "blocks" the javascript VM, thus delaying the UI build/update. Correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will.  While a synchronous request is outstanding, the browser waits for it to return.   The probability of that happening is 100%, but if your request returns fast enough, it might not be that noticeable.  Thing is, you can't count on a request returning quickly.

That's the point of ajax calls.  The first **a** mean asynchronous, which means, "doesn't block".

Since ajax calls are asynchronous, your code can be anywhere when the request returns, which means you need a way to handle the response when the request does return.  That is why you use *callbacks* to handle the response.

Why don't you try it?

Comment: It's not that I didn't try it - I'm using it all the time! Was just wondering. This one leads to another question.. Thank you!