# Pause switch statement until AJAX success

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form inside a slider, and elements inside each section of the slider are controlled by their respective case in a switch statement. For example:

HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li class="slide">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        <span class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.next','.slide').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var slideIndex = $(this).closest('.slide').index();

        switch (slideIndex) {
            case 0:
                someFunction();
                break;
            case 1:
                anotherFunction();
                break;
            case 2:
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
                    data: 'some data',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response)
                            // Call slide();
                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
    slide();
});
```

The problem is, `slide()` is always called at the end of the click function. Is there a way to only call the function after that AJAX request has given a response?

**Edit**

I probably didn't make myself clear enough. I know I could just call `slide()` in the ajax response, but then I would also have to call it at the end of every switch case. The flow should look something like:

User clicks 'next'..

-> script checks which slide the user is on

-> do logic for that slide

-> `slide()`

Comment: Put `slide()` in the callback?

Comment: Yeah, that's sort of obvious, but then I would have to call `slide()` at the end of every switch case.

Comment: Yeah why not place it in each switch case?

Comment: I could, but I'd like to keep my code as DRY as possible. If there's a better way of doing this, I'm all ears :)

Answer (score 2):

`$.ajax` returns a promise, so you can respond to the `done` event that the promise raises:

```
$(function(){
    $('.next').click(function (e) {
        var ajaxPromise;
        e.preventDefault();

        var slideIndex = $(this).attr("id");

        switch (slideIndex) {
            case 0:
                someFunction();
                break;
            case 1:
                anotherFunction();
                break;
            case 2:
                ajaxPromise = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
                    data: 'some data'
                });
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }

        if (ajaxPromise) {
            // execute when the promise is finished
            ajaxPromise.done(slide);
        } else {
            // execute immediately
            slide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

HTML

```
<ul class="slider">
    <li class="slide">
        <span id="0" class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        <span id="1" class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
    <li class="slide">
        <span id="2" class="next">Next</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.next').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var slideIndex = $(this).attr("id");

        switch (slideIndex) {
            case 0:
                someFunction();
                break;
            case 1:
                anotherFunction();
                break;
            case 2:
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
                    data: 'some data',
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response)
                            slide();
                    }
                break;
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
});
```

Comment: I think you missed the problem, which is having a call to slide in each switch branch after the respective action is done.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is asynchronous right.. So by the time the response is out the Slide() function will have been called already

instead of calling the slide() at the end of the function why don't you  call the function in the success of the ajax itself.

Also you are not closing your ajax method properly..

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
      data: 'some data',
      success: function (response) {
          if (response)
            slide();
          }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can move the call to slide into the success callback.  Then it will only be called on success.

Answer (score 0):

Remove slide from the bottom and modify the AJAX call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
    data: 'some data',
    success: function (response) {
        if (response)
            slide();
    },
    complete: function(){
        break;
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);//always do it, you never know when the AJAX call throws error
    }
});
```

Basically, don't let the case break before the AJAX call is complete.

Comment: This looked quite promising, but it gives a JS error: `Illegal break statement`.

Comment: Did you use it within the switch case block?

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a var callSlide in the click function, set it to true, and only call the slide() at the end if callSlide is true. Only set it to false in case 2:

```
$(function(){
 $('.next','.slide').click(function (e) {
    var callSlide = true;

    e.preventDefault();

    var slideIndex = $(this).closest('.slide').index();

    switch (slideIndex) {
        case 0:
            someFunction();
            break;
        case 1:
            anotherFunction();
            break;
        case 2:
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://some.site.com/register.php",
                data: 'some data',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response)
                        slide();
                }
            });
            callSlide = false;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

   if(callSlide)
     slide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Per another stack overflow post:

[How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)

You can have the ajax call performed synchronously. I wouldn't normally recommend it, but it is a possible solution...

Comment: This is a rather bad idea, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214573).