# Memory leaks when using AJAX JSON call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, performance, memory-leaks

In my javascript application I have big memory leak when making `AJAX` call to retrieve `JSON` object. Code is really simple:

```
function getNewMessage()
{
    new_message = []; // this is global variable
    var input_for_ball = [];
    var sum;
    var i;

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("GET", url + "/random_ball.json", false);
    http.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200)
        {
            var responseTxt = http.responseText;
            input_for_ball = JSON.parse('[' + responseTxt + ']');
        }
    }
    http.send(null);

    new_message = input_for_ball;
}
```

This is called every 1 milisecond and as you see, its synchronous call. This function costs me 1MB every 1 second.

When I use instead of `AJAX` just assigning to variable like:

```
 input_for_ball = JSON.parse('[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]');
```

then its everything perfect. So error must be in my implementation of `AJAX` call. This happened when I use `jQuery AJAX` call too.

**UPDATE 12/03/2013**

As `Tom van der Woerdt` mentioned below, this really was intended behavior. So as `Matt B.` suggested, I have rewrote some code to make asynchronous calls possible and it helped a lot. Now my application memory consuming is stable and small.

Comment: This doesn't have to be a memory leak, it could simply be a browser cache thing. Try letting it run for a while and see whether it keeps growing, maybe even into your swap. If it does, it's a memory leak. If it stops growing after a while, this is simply normal browser behavior.

Comment: I have tested it for about an hour at that time it was ~330MB, started at 100MB. Maybe test it in different browsers?

Comment: JavaScript is a language that controls all the memory stuff for you. If you think there's a memory leak in your code, you're either storing a lot of data in some global object, the interpreter has a bug, or it's intended behavior. Since your code doesn't store in a global object, and the browser only used ~330MB after an hour, I'd say that this is intended behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it's the AJAX call, but the closure which is costing you memory.  Your onreadystatechange function references the http object (so a reference to this will be kept with the anonymous function).
I think your code matches the pattern in example 1 in this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/

If you've not come across closures in javascript before, they're well worth reading up on - understanding them explains a lot of behaviour which doesn't seem to make sense at first glance.

Comment: Would setting http = null at the end of the callback be sufficient to free the memory?

Comment: @GHC Now I tried to comment line: `http.onreadystatechange = function()` and closures and still consumes +- same amount of memory.

Comment: @MattB. with `http = null` nad `delete http` its the same.

Comment: Have you tried it with an asynchronous call? Switching to asynchronous might be a good idea anyway, otherwise you're blocking the UI pretty much continuously since your code runs every millisecond. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214573/can-a-synchronous-blocking-ajax-call-block-the-browsers-ui

Comment: @MattB. Okay it wasn't that, with asynchronous call I don't have any response at all.

Comment: @kamylko Well with an asynchronous call your code would have to be a little different...you'd need to set `new_message = input_for_ball` at the end of the callback rather than where you have it now, since if the call is asynchronous it wouldn't have finished yet where you have that line now.

Comment: I strongly suggest making it asynchronous in any case unless you have a strong technical reason that it *must* be synchronous...AJAX works much better that way, and gives a better user experience.