# how to simulate a synchronous ajax call? (synchronous based on asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, ajax

Since "native" synchronous ajax call blocks the browser user interface it doesn't fit most of real world cases (mine at least).

I'd like to know if **there's any way to simulate a synchronous (blocking) ajax call, using an asynchronous (NON-blocking) ajax call**, so that the result would be a synchronous call but without blocking the UI.

The following code explains it better:

```
function do_synchronous_ajax_call(url){
    // Performs an asynchronous ajax call, which doesn't block the UI, BUT, blocks this current script execution
}

var xyz = do_synchronous_ajax_call("http://...."); // Call is blocking until the inner ajax call returns
// Process `xyz` from here
```

As you see, the above wishes to have some sort of **"synthetic" synchronous ajax call**, which **does NOT block the UI**.

Javascript doesn't support multi-threading so that might be impossible, but worth asking.

This is the third question in the subject.
These questions followed me to the current question:
[how to block on ajax call (I want it to block)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213889/how-to-block-on-ajax-call-i-want-it-to-block)
[can a synchronous (blocking) ajax call block the browser's UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214573/can-a-synchronous-blocking-ajax-call-block-the-browsers-ui#12214614)

Comment: Asynchronous AJAX calls do not block the UI; that's pretty much the end of the story. Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the UI to get updated, the execution needs to be handed back to the browser and the only way to do that is by asynchronous code (or otherwise code that immediately returns)

Answer (score 0):

Why "block" something if you can simply do nothing instead? It seems like you actually don't understand asynchronous flow. You don't "wait" - you instead declare what to do when data is available. Set up your request with callback that will contain rest of your code, dispatch request and return from Javascript, leaving browser to do its own task until it is time for your code to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a globally available lock. Whether you're using a global variable or if you have an object set that holds any options or objects at a global level you can simply have a boolean lock.

```
function do_ajax_call(url)
{
    if (!locked)
    {
        // yadda yadda yadda
        locked = true;

        myxmlhttpobj.onreadystatechange = HandleCallback;
    }
}

function HandleCallback() {
    if (myxmlhttpobj.readyState==4 && myxmlhttpobj.status==200)
    {
         // more yadda yadda
    }

    locked = false;
}
```

If you switch to [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you will gain the benefit of a whole host of framework events and methods including "beforeSend" which would allow to you apply a similar locking mechanism in conjuction with the "done" event.