# Ajax wont let me return true or false

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to return true for the entire validator.registercallback function if the following ajax script doesn't return 1.  However, it isn't working, and I think its probably something basic that I'm missing, but I can't figure it out.

```
validator.registerCallback('unique_username', function(value) {

        //use ajax to run the check  
        var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      if(xmlhttp.responseText != 1) {
          alert('Username Exists');
          return false;
      } else {
          alert('Username Available!');
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","uniqueuser.php?username="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();

})
```

What's weird is that the following works, it just doesn't work based on the value of the ajax script:

```
validator.registerCallback('unique_username', function(value) {

        //use ajax to run the check  
        var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
      if(xmlhttp.responseText != 1) {
          alert('Username Exists');
          return false;
      } else {
          alert('Username Available!');
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","uniqueuser.php?username="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();

return true;

})
```

So basically, I can tell it to return true in the main function, but when I try to make it return true ONLY IF the value in the ajax script doesn't return 1, it doesn't work.  By the way, the alerts DO WORK.  So it IS getting the right value, but it wont return true, or false for that matter.

Any help is appreciated!

*Update*

```
validator.registerCallback('unique_username', function(value) {

        //use ajax to run the check  
function ajax_result() {
  var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","uniqueuser.php?username="+value,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

if(ajax_result() != 1) { 

alert('Username Exists');
return false;

} else {

alert('Username Available!');
return true;

}

})
```

Comment: Search for "ajax return value" the *asynchronous* bit is of particular importance .. also, consider using a library for AJAX (and no, I don't care which one, but since *you tagged it as jQuery*..)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success - jQuery, but should show the point (and how to write cleaner code) and if you want *synchronous* behavior (ick!) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery

Comment: I tried using the jquery version but it didnt work either

Comment: This is as close as I've gotten, and also, I am still unsure what I should look at

Comment: What if you use validator.registerCallback using a non-anonymous function as second parameter? (you give a function name there instead). That is a function you can call from anywhere then. Which includes the handler where the webpage has been retrieved (in my jQuery solution).

Comment: But I have to admit I dont see the point of the callback being called. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is that the ajax call is **asynchronous**. When your function ends, the ajax call has not been completed yet, and the value (true or false) will only be returned later.

To address this, you need to either make the ajax call synchronous or modify your chaining logic, for example reverse it and run validator.registerCallback() inside the ajax call. You could also consider some more sophisticated techniques like [promises](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

[Update] This is how you make the request synchronous:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","uniqueuser.php?username="+value,false);
```

You'll also need to change the rest of the code, see for example [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

Comment: how do I make it synchronous?

Comment: I looked it up but i cant find where to put async = false in my code

Answer (score 0):

You have added jQuery to the list of keywords to this question so I answer using jQuery:

```
var username = "foo";
$.get('uniqueuser.php', {username: username}, function(webpage)
{
  if (webpage == 1)
    alert("user exists");
  else
    alert("Username available!");
});
```

Comment: `validator.registerCallback('unique_username', function(value) {
  
    var username = value;
$.get('uniqueuser.php', {username: username}, function(webpage)
{
  if (webpage == 1) {
    alert("Username Available!");
 return true;
} else {
    alert("Username Exists");
 return false;
}
});

})`

When I did this I got the alerts right, but its not returning the function true or false

Comment: I want to return true or false for the function `function(value)` within the validator

Comment: Ah, maybe you need to put the code I was writing in a function that takes two parameters, function is_user_existing(username, continuation), continuation is a function object that will be called with the result of the ajax call. Then you use is_user_existing('foo', function(result) { /* do someting */ }); and result is either true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Trying again:

```
is_user_existing('foo', function(result)
{
  if (result)
    alert("user is existing");
  else
    alert("user is not existing");
});

function is_user_existing(username, continuation)
{
    $.get('uniqueuser.php', {username: username}, function(webpage)
    {
      continuation (webpage == 1);
    });
}
```

Comment: The reason for not having an ordinary return value from is_user_existing is that the function returns before the ajax call has got a result

Comment: I dont know how to fix that...  I edited your answer with what I tried, and isnt working

Comment: I'm still trying to return true or false to `validator.registerCallback('unique_username', function(value)`

Comment: the `function(value)` is just not getting it

Comment: Its a part of a form validation script...  I need it because if it returns false, it wont let the user submit the form

Comment: Maybe you can modify a hidden variable from somewhere? <input type="hidden" name="is_username_available" value="false"/>, and then in script you $('[is_username_available'].val(webpage == 1 ? "true" : "false");

Comment: And then you add validation to that hidden field, is that possible to do?

Comment: Maybe, let me try something along those lines

Comment: `validator.registerCallback('updateusername', function(value) {
  
    var username = value;
$.get('uniqueuser.php', {username: username}, function(webpage)
{
  if (webpage == 1) {
    alert("Username Available!");
 document.getElementsByName('usernameused').value=='True';
    }else{
    alert("Username Exists");
 document.getElementsByName('usernameused').value=='False';
}
});

})`

Comment: Assign with = instead of ==