# Call a REST-based service synchronous with jQuery

Tags: jquery, rest, synchronous

I'm used to making AJAX calls, but since those are executed asynchronously, further in my code I'm unsure whether that call has already been completed. So in the codesample below, when I call alert(url), it might be that the lat and lng variables have not been filled yet.

So instead of making an AJAX call, I want my code to wait for the results before continuing, so a synchronous request.

How can I do so?

```
 var url='';

 if ($('select[name="countryselect"]').val() != '0') { url += '&country=' + $('#countryselect option:selected').text(); }

if ($('#<%=tbCity.ClientID%>').val() != '') {
             url += '&distance=' + $('#<%=ddlDistance.ClientID%>').val();

             $.ajax({
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "/service.svc/getlocs/?cid=" + countryid
                    + "&c=" + $('#<%=tbCity.ClientID%>').val(),
                 data: "",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 success: function (msg) {
                     url += '&lat=' + msg[0].value;
                     url += '&lng=' + msg[1].value;
                 }
             });


         }

alert(url);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronous calls with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942544/synchronous-calls-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use ajax, but move everything that needs to happen after into your success handler:

```
         $.ajax({
             type: "GET",
             url: "/service.svc/getlocs/?cid=" + countryid
                + "&c=" + $('#<%=tbCity.ClientID%>').val(),
             data: "",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (msg) {
                 url += '&lat=' + msg[0].value;
                 url += '&lng=' + msg[1].value;
                 alert(url);
                 // more work here
             }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

> So in the codesample below, when I call alert(url), it might be that the lat and lng variables have not been filled yet.

It will definitely not have been filled in. The request is done asynchronously, it has not even started at that time. It needs to wait for its "turn".

What you should be doing is put all the code that needs to run after the request in the "success" callback of the Ajax request.

> So instead of making an AJAX call, I want my code to wait for the results before continuing, so a synchronous request.

I don't know if synchronous requests are even possible on modern browsers anymore, but even if, they are a terrible idea, because it would be not just your code waiting, but the whole page execution would freeze. No timers updating, the user cannot click anywhere else, etc.

You need to learn to work with callbacks.